# Keras conv1d layer parameters: filters and kernel_size

Tags: keras, convolution

I am very confused by these two parameters in the conv1d layer from keras:
https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv1d

the documentation says:

```
filters: Integer, the dimensionality of the output space (i.e. the number output of filters in the convolution).
kernel_size: An integer or tuple/list of a single integer, specifying the length of the 1D convolution window.
```

But that does not seem to relate to the standard terminologies I see on many tutorials such as https://adeshpande3.github.io/adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner's-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks/ and https://machinelearningmastery.com/sequence-classification-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/

Using the second tutorial link which uses Keras, I'd imagine that in fact 'kernel_size' is relevant to the conventional 'filter' concept which defines the sliding window on the input feature space. But what about the 'filter' parameter in conv1d? What does it do?

For example, in the following code snippet:

```
model.add(embedding_layer)
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=100, kernel_size=4, padding='same', activation='relu'))
```

suppose the embedding layer outputs a matrix of dimension 50 (rows, each row is a word in a sentence) x 300 (columns, the word vector dimension), how does the conv1d layer transforms that matrix?

Many thanks

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You're right to say that `kernel_size` defines the size of the sliding window.

The `filters` parameters is just how many different windows you will have. (All of them with the same length, which is `kernel_size`). How many different results or channels you want to produce.

When you use `filters=100` and `kernel_size=4`, you are creating 100 different filters, each of them with length 4. The result will bring 100 different convolutions.

Also, each filter has enough parameters to consider all input channels.

---

The Conv1D layer expects these dimensions:

```
(batchSize, length, channels)
```

I suppose the best way to use it is to have the number of words in the length dimension (as if the words in order formed a sentence), and the channels be the output dimension of the embedding (numbers that define one word).

So:

```
batchSize = number of sentences    
length = number of words in each sentence   
channels = dimension of the embedding's output.
```

The convolutional layer will pass 100 different filters, each filter will slide along the `length` dimension (word by word, in groups of 4), considering all the channels that define the word.

The outputs are shaped as:

```
(number of sentences, 50 words, 100 output dimension or filters)
```

The filters are shaped as:

```
(4 = length, 300 = word vector dimension, 100 output dimension of the convolution)
```

Comment: How are the filters positioned? Say we have a vector [0..99], kernel_size=10, filters=3. From what I understand, filters will overlap each other, so they would go like [0..9], [1..10], [2..11], and we've just ran out of filters, having only covered 12 first values from the vector. Do I get it right?

Comment: No, you described the sequential operations performed by a single filter. The same filter travels along the entire vector. Filter 1 will go [0..9], [1..10],[2..11] ... until [90..99]. Filter 2, which is beside filter 1, will also go  [0..9], [1..10],[2..11] ... until [90..99]. And filter 3, also beside the other filters, will follow the same path.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense :). One thing still bothers me though. While processing a single data row, 1st conv layer gets the row and outputs 100 transformed rows (one from each filter) right? How would it be digested by a 2nd conv layer (say, a one with 50 filters)? Would the 2nd layer output 100*50 rows?

Comment: Right, the first layers outputs 100 "channels". But the second outputs only 50 channels. It happens that the filters in the second layers will be filters that not only take 3 elements from a channel, but 3 elements from all 100 channels, and do each step of the convolution with 300 elements at once.

Comment: @DanielMöller are filters randomly initialized? If my understanding is correct, after every iteration, the values of the of the filters are changed to be more representative of what the filter needs to filter out. The question is after an X number of iterations (the model has converged, the training is complete), are most of the filters for a given output the same? If so, what is the benefit of having lots of filters?

Comment: @Gevo12321, yes, filters are randomly initialized. Because of this, each filter follows a different evolution. No, the filters don't tend to the same result. They tend to the best result considering all the futher layers until the end. They form a huge combination of possibilities to represent complex things. A single filter cannot do this alone.

Comment: Is it possible to generate convlutions with multiple kernel sizes? So instead of 100 filters produced through a kernel of size 4, can I generate 50 each with kernels of size 3 and 5?

Comment: @Shailesh, with two parallel layers, and a concatenation, yes, easily. You must learn about Functional API models. Can't do that with Sequential models.

Answer (score 1):

Below code from the explanation can help do this. I went similar question and answered it myself.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPool1D
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D 
tf.random.set_seed(1) # nowadays instead of tf.set_random_seed(1)

batch,rows,cols = 3,8,3
m, n, k = batch, rows, cols
input_shape = (batch,rows,cols)

np.random.seed(132) # nowadays instead of np.set_random_seed = 132
data = np.random.randint(low=1,high=6,size=input_shape,dtype='int32')
data = np.float32(data)
data = tf.constant(data)

print("Data:")
print(K.eval(data))
print()
print(f'm,n,k:{input_shape}')
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D

#############################
# Understandin filters and kernel_size
##############################
num_filters=5
kernel_size= 3

'''
Few Notes about Kernel_size:
1. max_kernel_size == max_rows
2. since Conv1D, we are creating 1D Matrix of 1's with kernel_size 
if kernel_size = 1, [[1,1,1..]]
if kernel_size = 2, [[1,1,1..][1,1,1,..]]
if kernel_size = 3, [[1,1,1..][1,1,1,..]]

I have chosen tf.keras.initializers.constant(1) to create a matrix of Ones.
Size of matrix is Kernel_Size

'''
y= Conv1D(filters=num_filters,kernel_size=kernel_size,
          kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(1), 
 #glorot_uniform(seed=12)
          input_shape=(k,n)
         )(data)
#########################
# Checking the out outcome
#########################
print(K.eval(y))
print(f' Resulting output_shape == (batch_size, num_rows-kernel_size+1,num_filters): {y.shape}')

# # Verification
K.eval(tf.math.reduce_sum(data,axis=(2,1), # Sum along axis=2, and then along 
 axis=1,keep_dims=True)



###########################################
# Understanding MaxPool and Strides in 
##########################################
pool = MaxPool1D(pool_size=3,strides=3)(y)
print(K.eval(pool))
print(f'Shape of Pool: {pool.shape}')
```

Comment: `tf.random.set_seed(1)` nowadays