# How do convolutional filters look like in Keras?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, convolution

I'm working with [convolutional layers](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) in Keras and found this brilliant [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46503816/keras-conv1d-layer-parameters-filters-and-kernel-size). I assume that the following code:

```
model.add(Conv1D(filters=5, kernel_size=4, padding='same', activation='relu'))
```

would create 5 filters each having a size of 4. Thus, if my (1-D) input would look as follows:

```
[x_0,x_1,x_2_x_3,x_4]
```

, I would end up with the following output:

```
[o_{00},o_{01}}
[o_{10},o_{11}}
[o_{20},o_{21}}
[o_{30},o_{31}}
[o_{40},o_{41}}
```

Here, [x_0,x_1,x_2_x_3,x_4] represents my input sequence and o_{00} stands for the output of the first filter window of the first filter containing 4 elements and o_{01} stands for the output of the second filter window of the first filter containing 4 elements, etc...

Am I correct so far?

Now, if the filters would all contain the same numbers, this wouldn't make any sense and thus I assume that all the created filters must contain different numbers. But how are those filters created? Are they just filled with random numbers in Keras or is there any sophisticated algorithm at work?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Your question makes very little sense to me, the only thing I can say is that the filters are indeed filled with random numbers at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. That's indeed what I wanted to know. What about my question, though? Am I wrong somewhere or is it unclear?

Comment: Yes, the x_i and o_ij thingies are completely unclear to me, they seem to be unrelated to the essence of the question.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I edited the question to make it (hopefully) clearer.